# Popup for tag wiki excerpt misplaced while editing tags

Tags: bug, tag-wiki-excerpt

I have noticed that when I select edit tags and I hover a tag, the popup that shows the tag's wiki excerpt is misplaced - instead of right below the tag it is at the top left of the screen.

[image]

I don't think this is a desired behavior. My browser is Google Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152 and I am using 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04.